# Want to show alert dialog across activities

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to show an `Alert Dialog` such that it stays on screen even if I go back to previous activity just after showing an alert dialog. Is is possible?

I tried using `applicationContext` but it does not work.

Comment: I don't think so, and I believe this would be an awful user experience.

Comment: @AndyRes Ok. In iOS version of my app, when I go back to previous activity the alert stays on screen. I don't need to do anything. I need this when user should not be on that screen any longer, but before going back I need to display the reason.

Comment: If I understand you correct, you want to go from let say `Activity A` to `Activity B`, and when returning back to `Activity A` to display a dialog, right? If this is so, then you can start `Activity B` with `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`, and override `onActivityResult()` where you'll show the dialog.

Comment: @AndyRes I accept that it is not possible to show same dialog across activity. You can post your statements as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, and I believe this would be a bad user experience. Perhaps you should re-think the design.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that , because a dialog is attached with a single window context , if window changes the dialog memory will be leaked and it will automatically close the dialog .You can make a same effect by showing the same dialog in both screens .However you will definitely see the transition of dialog with activity .

Answer (score 0):

You can create an activity and give it a dialog theme. That way you dont have to worry about the context. It doesnt make a difference to the user also as it looks just like a dialog.

But I agree with AndyRes, It would be a bad user experience.